# Representing hierarchical structures in otp

Tags: erlang, structure, erlang-otp

I want to dive a little bit deeper into erlang and because I have a computer game background I thought to make a very simple game server, nothing fancy. 
I am thinking about making a world of interconnected solar systems but I am not sure how to represent the hierarchical structure in supervisors and genservers.

One way to look at it would be that the solar system, the planets, etc would be supervisors that watch over their children. This does not work I suppose, because supervisors are not meant to store state and the each planet, moon etc has a state. 
That means that everything must be a genserver and that leads to the conclusion that I need to create a hierarchy of genservers. 
How does that fit into the concept of supervisors and genservers?

Comment: I've got a hunch that you're trying to merge two different concepts here:
1) model of the application you write and
2) model of the world/data you want to operate on.
I'll try to elaborate once I have a spare minute.

Comment: That might be. Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it is good idea to split state between multiple `gen_servers`, but the content hierarchy doesn't have to be connected with supervision tree. You can read more about [supervision principles](http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-4.9.1/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html).

Generally, when thinking about supervisors, you think about crashing. Lets say, that the `gen_server` holding Moon state crashes. The question is: does Earth depend on the state of the Moon? If yes, then you have to restart the Earth `gen_server` after Moon crash and this is a hunch, that they have to be under one supervisor with `one_for_all` restart strategy. If they are independent, you can have all your heavenly bodies under one supervisor with `one_for_one` restart strategy and it would have nothing to do with actual content hierarchy.

If you decide, that you need that hierarchy, you can do it this way:

```
- application supervisor
    + universe gen_server
    - univserse supervisor
         + solar system gen_server
         - solar system supervisor
             + planet gen_server
             - planet supervisor
                 + moon gen_server
                 + moon2 gen_server
         + another solar system gen_server
         - another solar system supervisor
```

Depending on restart strategies, you can now restart entire universe, if universe `gen_server` crashes or entire planet, when one of its moon crashes, because you can also decide to crash parent supervisor, when one of its children crashes.

So - think first about how the `gen_servers` depend on each other and if you can - make them as independent as possible. After that, check what shape of supervision tree and restart strategies you need in case of failure.

Comment: Ah, ok. That means that I would create my content hierarchy (moon is child if earth I.e.) as gen_servers with lists for example and the supervision tree is "just" for automatic restarting the systems. That makes sense. I was focussing too much on the hierarchy aspect. Thank you very much.

Comment: Now remember how this will affect gameplay. Is the Moon a zone and the Earth another zone? If so, why should everyone on the Moon get bounced just because the Earth zone crashed? Think about how you want the map put together before you commit to a hierarchy. But write *something* now, whichever way you decide -- you'll learn something either way -- my whole point is to consider how your supervision tree will impact your gameplay/ui/usability/etc.